# WPF XAML bind resource key to property

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a set of icons stored in a file named Icons.xaml in MyProject/Resource.

```
<!-- Icons.xaml -->
<DrawingImage x:Key="CounterClockWiseDirection">...</DrawingImage>
<DrawingImage x:Key="ClockWiseDirection">...</DrawingImage>
```

In my ViewModel there's a property named ClockWiseDirection which should control this image.

```
<!-- MyControUC.xaml -->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFromList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Image Grid.Column="1" />
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{StaticResource CurrentItem.ClockWiseDirection}" />
                <Image Grid.Column="3" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This obviously doesn't work, I'm quite new to WPF so I'm bit confused about the solution to use/look.

Comment: <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{StaticResource  ClockWiseDirection}" /> should work, assuming that your Icons.xaml is loaded in the app.xaml

Comment: No, it doesn't. ViewModel's property is defined as public string ClockWiseDirection{get;set;}

Comment: ViewModel ? StaticResouce has nothing to do with your ViewModel.

Comment: Code edited hoping to be clearer.

Comment: You have to distinguish between StaticResource/DynamicResouce/Binding. When you want to bind to DataContext or ViewModel object you should use Source="{Binding ...}", StatickResource/DynamicResouce is to be used when you want to refer to resources you have specified in XAML, either in App.xaml or somewhere else in your application

Comment: @IssamTP: Are you trying to return a resource *key* from the view model? Why? Return the actual `DrawingImage` instead and *bind* to it: `Source="{Binding ClockWiseDirection}"`. Or please explain your set up in detail.

Comment: @mm8 that would be fine too, is there some way to load them?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to return a resource *key* from the view model. You might as well return the actual `DrawingImage` instead and *bind* to it in your XAML markup:

```
Source="{Binding ClockWiseDirection}"
```

If the resource that is defined in your Icons.xaml `ResourceDictionary` is in scope, you could get a reference to it by calling `FindResource` and cast the result:

```
ClockWiseDirection = `FindResource("CounterClockWiseDirection") as DrawingImage;`
```

The other option is to create a `ResourceDictionary` object dynamically and get the resource from there:

```
ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("Themes/generic.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) };
ClockWiseDirection = rd["CounterClockWiseDirection"] as DrawingImage;
```

Comment: I'll try the FindResource way and let you know.